# logging in with SSO account instead of specified credentials in the script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am running an python automation script to login to specific application and I have specified the credentials in the script but when the browser is running, it is taking my SSO instead of the credentials that I have added in the script. Can anyone help me with this

I tried clearing the history and cache and restarted my system. Then, at first it logged in through the credentials I have provided in the automation script but in the second attempt again my SSO email is used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.